# Unexpected output from php -v

Tags: php

Just ran php -v on my Centos 5 server and got the following message back.

```
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules//php_ioncube_loader_lin_5.1_x86_64.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules//php_ioncube_loader_lin_5.1_x86_64.so: undefined symbol: zend_unmangle_property_name_ex
PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2011 10:39:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

PHP seems to be running okay, but I don't like the look of that message.  What does this message mean, and what should I do?  (I don't want to upgrade to 5.3 as some client sites still use deprecated in PHP 5.3 functions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it seems you have an incompatible version of [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/) installed. I have never used ioncube, but I would guess that if you have updated PHP after installing ioncube, you might need to reinstall it ... however that happens. Just a wild guess. :)

Comment: Spot on, thank you.  For reference I just used `yum install php-ioncube-loader` and it's all sorted.